# Enable/Disable Clear button based on the search criteria

Tags: jquery

There are 3 text fields in a search form and a clear button in it.

Here is what I want to do -

1 - First the clear button will be disabled

2 - When the text is entered in any one of the text boxes then the Clear button will be enabled

3 - The Clear button will be disabled only when there is no text in either of the text boxes.

4 - We can also add more search criteria. That means there can be any number of text boxes

Here is my code:

```
var toValidate = $("#basicSearchFields input"),
clearBtn = $("#clearBasicSearch");

toValidate.keyup(function () {
toValidate.each(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        valid = true;
    } else {
        valid = false;
    }
    (valid === true) ? clearBtn.removeClass('disabled') : clearBtn.addClass('disabled');
});
});
```

Actually what this code is doing when text is entered into any of the text boxes the button is getting enabled but clearing the texts from the text box is not disabling the button again. Please help me out!!

Comment: Ok,sure we will help.Show us your code.

Comment: have you tried anything till now ?? if yes then put it here

Comment: var toValidate = $("#basicSearchFields input"),
    clearBtn = $("#clearBasicSearch");

toValidate.keyup(function () {
    toValidate.each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            valid = false;
        }
        (valid === true) ? clearBtn.removeClass('disabled') : clearBtn.addClass('disabled');
    });
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to suggestions then here is an easy way to achieve what you are trying to do

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LjCQ5/1/)

Sample HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="search" />
    <input type="text" class="search" />
    <input type="text" class="search" />

    <button id="clearFields" disabled="disabled">Clear</button>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".search").keyup(function(){
    $("#clearFields").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".search").each(function(){
        if(this.value.length > 0){
            $("#clearFields").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Code to make the clear button work

```
$("#clearFields").click(function(){
  $(".search").each(function(){
        this.value = "";
  });
});
```

Comment: Can we also add/remove disable css class to this in addition to disabled attribute

Comment: @user2080056 Unfortunately even though we have display/visible properties, enable/disable is not a CSS property. It is an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate, the selector will perform the same function for all the selected elements in the "toValidate" variable.

```
//Encapsulate the logic in a function that receives the context 
//and also the jQuery reference to the clear button
function ValidateContext(sToValidateSelector, jqClearButton) {
    var jqValidate = $(sToValidateSelector);

    //Bind/Re-bind the event (off/on) to prevent multi call to the same context.
    jqValidate
        .off('keyup')
        .on('keyup',function () {
            jqElement = $(this);
            jqClearButton.prop('disabled', jqElement.val().length == 0);
        });
}
```

Call the function for one or more contexts:

```
ValidateContext('#form1 input', $('#clearButton1'));
ValidateContext('#form2 input', $('#clearButton2'));
ValidateContext('#searchform input', $('#clearButtonSearch'));
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var toValidate = $("#basicSearchFields input:not(#clearBasicSearch)");
toValidate.keyup(function () {
    var valid = false; //default is false
    toValidate.each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            valid = true; //non-empty element found
            return false; //break
        }
    });

    $("#clearBasicSearch").toggleClass('disabled', !valid); //add if valid, remove if not
});
```

Comment: Not working. See this http://jsfiddle.net/mWHXA/. Button is not enabled if there is no text in any of the text boxes

Comment: Because "#clearBasicSearch" is an input as well. Change `var toValidate = $("#basicSearchFields input");` to a more specific selector like `var toValidate = $("#basicSearchFields input:not(#clearBasicSearch)");`

Comment: Thanks Breyndot.. It works.. Not sure why I could not figure it out